# how to define a specific scroll area on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, antd

I am writing a single page app for mobile use `antd-mobile`,

[image]

There's s a Tabbar on the bottom of the page, and a list of items that u can see the background is gray, the problem is the Tabbar cover the content of the when I scroll down to the bottom.

How can I make the list area to be scroll area not the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

Some code could help us help you... But there is multiple strategies you could use, all depending on your actual code and what you'd prefer to achieve.

1. Use `margin-bottom` on `body`. This will add a margin to the bottom of your pages, having it set to the height of your *Tabbar*, this will ensure that it never hides the bottom content. That is assuming your *Tabbar* is in a fixed position. This solution will make the scroll bar show on the entire page.
2. Use a defined content holder `height`, and set `overflow-y:scroll`. You could set the height of your content holder to be 100vh minus the height of your *Tabbar*. This way it is "fullscreen" and you can then apply `overflow-y:scroll` to make that part scrollable. This will display a scroll bar on the element, not the entire page.